# Create a slide popup in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component for an ecommerce shop in ReactJS.

I want to create a summary popup that slides down from the top of the screen every time a user adds a product to the cart. The popup should slide down, wait for 3 seconds and then slide up again.

All I can think of is a static div that I return in the `render` method of a component.

Please, if you have ideas or links to examples?

Thanks, Alon

Comment: Use a react library for animation to save yourself headaches. Try React motion.

Comment: I found this exmaple with buttons

Comment: I found this exmaple with buttons.
is there any option to use this code and create something that will fade away automaticly after 3 seconds

https://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/3fkso0kq/

Answer (score 0):

According to the example you attached to your comment,
You can use timeout and change the state after three seconds for it to disappear.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({thingIsVisible: false});
}, 3000);
```

That way you can make it show and disappear on your choice.